# How to calculate the GED between g2 and q?

Tags: networkx, graph-theory

I am learning the networkx function named "networkx.graph_edit_distance(g2,q)". Actually, GED(g2,q) = 2.If we want to tranform g2 to q, we should do at least 2 graph edit operations"substituing (1,3) whose label is '2' in g2 to (1,3) whose label is '1', inserting (3,4) which is not exsits in g2 to (3,4) whose label 
is '1".My code is shown below:[image]

```
nodes = [(1,{'label':'C1'}),
     (2,{'label':'C2'}),
     (3,{'label':'C3'}),
     (4,{'label':'C4'}),
     (5,{'label':'N'})]
edges = [(1,2,{'label':'1'}),
         (2,4,{'label':'1'}),
         (4,5,{'label':'1'}),
         (5,3,{'label':'1'}),
         (3,1,{'label':'2'})]
g2 = nx.Graph()
g2.add_nodes_from(nodes)
g2.add_edges_from(edges)

nodes = [(1,{'label':'C1'}),
         (2,{'label':'C2'}),
         (3,{'label':'C3'}),
         (4,{'label':'C4'}),
         (5,{'label':'N'})]
edges = [(1,2,{'label':'1'}),
         (2,4,{'label':'1'}),
         (4,5,{'label':'1'}),
         (5,3,{'label':'1'}),
         (3,1,{'label':'1'}),
         (3,4,{'label':'1'})]
q = nx.Graph()
q.add_nodes_from(nodes)
q.add_edges_from(edges)

GED_q_g2 = nx.graph_edit_distance(g2, q)
```

But unfortunately, the expected answer is GED =2， but it gives the answer GED_q_g2  = 1.Please how could I get the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the defined graph, the edit distance of 1 is correct, because only `(3,4)` needs to be removed.

The graph that you've drawn displays two edges between 1 and 3, though. I guess you've misunderstood the `label` functionality: It's just an optional data attribute that you can use for identification or plotting - it has nothing to do with the number of edges or weights.

If you want to use multiple edges between two nodes, have a look at [nx.Multigraph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multigraph.html?highlight=multigraph#networkx.MultiGraph).

Comment: The edge between 1 and 3 are not two edges, I just want to represent the edge whose label is '2'. and its real meaning in chemistry is the double bond between two atoms.The most important is that the graph is simple graph rather than mutiple graph.

Comment: Ah, I see. But changing the label of an edge is not considered as an editing operation that would count towards the edit distance. Only the removal and addition of an edge does. You'd need to add some custom logic that compares the edge labels for your use case. Or go with nx.Multigraph instead if your labels really mean one or more bonds between atoms.

Comment: A graph edit operation is an edit operation to transform one graph to another, including: insert an isolated labeled vertex into the graph;delete an isolated labeled vertex from the graph;change the label of a vertex; insert a labeled edge into the graph;delete a labeled edge from the graph; change the label of an edge. And you mention the "nx.Multigraph", could you give me the detailed  idea ?

Answer (score -1):

just use the `edge_match`.

```
nx.graph_edit_distance(g1,g2,edge_match=lambda a,b: a['label'] == b['label']))
```